# Is there any analogy in Ansible to AWS intrinsic function Fn::Cidr?

Tags: amazon-web-services, ansible, aws-cloudformation, subnet, vpc

I can obtain a list of VPC subnets using Ansible playbook:

```
  tasks:
    - name: Gathering VPC info ...
      amazon.aws.ec2_vpc_subnet_info:
        region: "eu-east-1"
        filters:
          vpc-id: vpc-433434432aad778ad
      register: output
  
    - name: Register new var
      ansible.builtin.set_fact:
        cidr_list: "{{ cidr_list|default([]) + [item.cidr_block] }}"
      loop: "{{ output.subnets }}"
      
    - name: Debugger...
      ansible.builtin.debug:
        msg: "{{ cidr_list }}"
```

What I want now is to calculate all IPv4 addresses by giving a size of each subnet and the initial VPC CIDR (this is actually successfully can be done using AWS Fn::Cidr):

```
"Fn::Cidr" : ["10.0.0.0/16", 15, 29 ]
```

Which will create a list of 15 subnets where each has a mask of /29. Then my goal is to compare two lists, and if not used IPv4 found from Fn::Cidr list, then use that one.

However I was wondering is there such an Ansible module to accomplish same task as would Fn::Cidr do?

Comment: I believe the [`| ipsubnet` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/collections/ansible/utils/docsite/filters_ipaddr.html#subnet-manipulation) will do what you want, but it may require some `{% for %}` loops because I don't think it is designed (ootb) to do 15 subnets at a time. Have you already tried it?

Comment: @ndaniel it does exactly what I want :) dunno how haven't I noticed that, please post it as an answer and I will upvote

Comment: I'm glad I was able to help. Don't forget you can [post and accept your own answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/self-answer), since mine is only a pointer in the right direction, but doesn't solve your original concern about the 15 subnets. If you post and accept how you replaced `Fn::CIDR` it would help others, too.

Comment: @mdaniel I haven't found exactly the right implementation of Fn::CIDR in Ansible, but I have used your solution + created Python script to find out the vacant subnet

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`| ipsubnet` filter](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/6/collections/ansible/utils/docsite/filters_ipaddr.html#subnet-manipulation) will do what you want, but it may require some `{% for %}` loops because I don't think it is designed (ootb) to do 15 subnets at a time